# Oauth not working CX api

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use the oauth for CX exposed api, I followed their documentation, still I'm getting HTTP "BAD REQUEST" error, Here is the code -

```
    String method = "POST";
    String code = "";
    NameValuePair[] data = {
                             new NameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                             new NameValuePair("code", code),
                             new NameValuePair("redirect_uri",URLEncoder.encode(CALLBACK_URL, "UTF-8"))              
                            }; 
    String secret = CONSUMER_KEY+":"+CONSUMER_SECRET;
    String encodedSecret = Base64.encodeBase64String(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient httpClient = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
    PostMethod httpMethod = new PostMethod(ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL);
    httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+encodedSecret);
    httpMethod.setRequestBody(data);
    System.out.println("HTTP call -- " + method + " " + ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL);
    httpClient.executeMethod(httpMethod);
```

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: Please provide a link to the API documentation, as it is not totally clear what provider "CX" you are referring to.

Comment: here it is -- http://developer.cx.com/docs

Comment: Have you tried this same code with a different OAuth provider, just to verify that the problem is with CX?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following slight modification of your code and it works. You might double check that

1. Your key has been approved (this shouldn't be the problem given the
   error you are seeing).
2. You are using the correct ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL
3. Try having the redirect_uri be the same for both the auth_code response and the token request

   ```
       String method = "POST";
       String authCode = "[AUTH-CODE-HERE]";
       String CONSUMER_KEY="[YOUR-KEY-HERE]";
       String CONSUMER_SECRET="[YOUR-SECRET-HERE]";
       String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL="https://api.cx.com/1/oauth/token";
       String REDIRECT_URI="[YOUR-REDIRECT-HERE]";

       NameValuePair[] data = {
               new NameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
               new NameValuePair("code", authCode),
               new NameValuePair("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI)
       };
       String secret = CONSUMER_KEY+":"+CONSUMER_SECRET;
       String encodedSecret = Base64.encodeBase64String(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

       PostMethod httpMethod = new PostMethod(ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL);
       httpMethod.addRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+encodedSecret);
       httpMethod.setRequestBody(data);
       System.out.println("HTTP call -- " + method + " " + ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL);
       int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(httpMethod);
       System.out.println(responseCode);
       System.out.println(httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
   ```

If you are still running into issues, can you post the result of the following line:       System.out.println(httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());

Answer (score 0):

The CX developer API has been discontinued. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.